# Landscape mode by programatic

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I am doing a new project in that I need both landscape and portrait view , I have designed my page. The portrait is working good but how to set landscape in programatic. help me dudes.

Comment: What do you mean by set landscape in programatic? Do you mean layout controls, views, etc.?

Comment: yes in programatic. i am not using xib. send me any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using viewDidLayoutSubviews like that:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
    if (bounds.size.width > bounds.size.height)
    {
        // landscape layout
        [self.myView setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 80.0f, 330.0f, 318.0f)];
    }
    else
    {
        // portrait layout
        [[self.myView setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 1500.0f, 318.0f)];
    }
}
```

It works fine for me. I assume that your app respond to orientation changes.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Supporting multiple interface orientations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW1). Also, if you do want to force some orientation when iOS decides to use another one, there's no way do it with public API.

Answer (score 0):

this is work for me:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (self.firstViewAppear) {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
        CGFloat duration = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientationAnimationDuration;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
        self.navigationController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        self.navigationController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*(90)/180.0);
        self.navigationController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.firstViewAppear = NO;

    }
    self.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:NO];
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

Comment: i having background image for landscape "LBG.png" and portrait "BG.png". where should i place the code here.

Comment: @janagowtham in `if (self.firstViewAppear) {}`

Comment: error is coming.how to set a property for firstViewAppear.

Comment: just to define a BOOL firstViewAppear  property in .h file. And in init set default value YES.